# Multiple preg_match_all result in foreach

Tags: php, regex, foreach, preg-match-all

I would like to replace each decimal number for later using in Javascript. so This is my code:

```
if (preg_match_all("#[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,8})#", $operationvalue_new2, $result)) {            
  foreach ($result[0] as $number_element) {                                                                                                      
    $operationvalue_new2 = preg_replace(
      "#[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,8})#", 
      "Number(\\0)", 
      $operationvalue_new2
    );
    #echo $operationvalue_new2;
  }              
};
```

Here is an example what happens:

> //var1812/100*(var1805*var1807*2.688)+(var1808-var1812)*var1806*var1807*1.2/100)

will be converted to

> //var1812/100*(var1805*var1807*Number(Number(2.688)))+(var1808-var1812)*var1806*var1807*Number(Number(1.2))/100)

but should be

> //var1818=var1812/100*(var1805*var1807*Number(2.688))+(var1808-var1812)*var1806*var1807*Number(1.2)/100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$subject = "var1812/100*(var1805*var1807*2.688)+(var1808-var1812)*var1806*var1807*1.2/100)";
$result = preg_replace('/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,8})/s', 'number($1)', $subject);
echo $result;
?>
```

Results in:

```
var1812/100*(var1805*var1807*number(2.688))+(var1808-var1812)*var1806*var1807*number(1.2)/100)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but it does not work here. Same Problem as before, number() will be replaced two times, perhaps problem is the foreach loop. Seems that it replaces each Number() again, as often a decimal is found...

Comment: Strange. The result displayed in my answer has been produced ba the corresponding script in reality. Maybe someone else could try it too. What version if PHP are you using?

Comment: Btw, why do you need a foreach loop. My solution does not.

Comment: PHP 5.6, regexp seem so be perfect for one replacement, perhaps problem is caused by another part, perhaps the first preg_match...

Comment: For the sample data you published in your question you would only need one _preg\_replace_.

Comment: "why do you need a foreach loop" > because there are more than one result, if expression is found. do i not need a foreach loop? there can also be perhaps 3 decimals or more to replace.